# 2Checkout - I canot see list of payment in account section

Tags: 2checkout

I am implementing 2checkout payment gateway on my website. After testing (sandbox mode), I failed to see any transaction on 2checkout dashboard after testing on my website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox sales will only be visible in your [2Checkout sandbox admin area](https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/). In your sandbox admin you can click on the "Sales" tab to view all of your sandbox sales. Please reach out to 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2co.com if you would like further assistance with your sandbox testing.

Comment: I am facing the same issue made payments successfully but when I see sales tab in sandbox admin area it shows "You have had 0 sales in the last 60 days" please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have turned off the demo settings under site settings in Account section.

https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/acct/detail_company_info

[image]

If demo mode is on, you can demo the payment in sandbox. But the sale will not listed in the sales.

Found following from 2checkout knowledge base.

"Unlike testing with Demo mode, the sales that you make in the Sandbox will appear in the Sandbox account's Sales tab, for you to review, refund, cancel recurrings and more with the Sandbox Sales Tools."

https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/sales/